# Using jQuery code, Want Input field on selecting other from the option?

Tags: html, jquery

```
 $('#add_ent_button').click(function() {
                        entrance_counter = entrance_counter + 1;
                        $('#entrance_counter').val(entrance_counter);
                            var html = '';
                            html += '<hr class="hr-primary" />';
                            html += '<div class="form-row">';
                            html += '<div class="form-group col-md-2">';
                            html += '<label>Entrance Exam Name</label>';
                            html += '<select class="form-control" name="entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'" onchange=showHideElement("txt-entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'") id="entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'">';
                            html += '<option value="">Select Entrance Exam</option>';
                            html += '<option>JEE</option>';
                            html += '<option>JEE Adv.</option>';
                            html += '<option>NEET</option>';
                            html += '<option>NATA</option>';
                            html += '<option value="other">other</option>';
                            html += '</select>';
                            html += '<input type="text" style="display:none;" name="txt-entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'" id="txt-entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'" class="form-control">';
                            html += '</div>';
```

This is the jQuery Code but in this line

```
html += '<select class="form-control" name="entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'" onchange=showHideElement("txt-entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'") id="entrance_exam'+entrance_counter+'">';
```

I am a bit confused I want to show the input field when the "other" option is selected from the dropdown. so when I choose "other" then it should call the function in onchange, but when I select other then it is not showing input fields I think the error is because of the quotes in the above jQuery line.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try This
This is Implemented in Raw JavaScript Convert To Jquery If Needed

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var other = document.getElementById('other');
other.onclick = function() {
  inp.style.display = "block";
  inp.focus();
  document.getElementById('select').style.display = 'none';
}
inp.onblur = function() {
  // if input  has no value then it will be hidden and option will be active again 
  if (inp.value == '') {
    document.getElementById('select').style.display = 'block';
    inp.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Other Click to inputr</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="select-input">
    <select name="" id="select">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="other" id="other">Other</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" value="" id="inp">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```